# Writing a series of variables to a text file+ adding comments

Tags: r, ubuntu

So let's say I have a script which gives me as output a series of variables:

```
mean=3
median=6
std=5
```

And I have to write them to a txt file and do multiple recalculations of those variables. So I would like to have a text file written like:

```
#######Iteration number 1#############
Mean=3
median=6
std=5

#######Iteration number 2################

Mean=4
median=7
std=6.5
```

Instead of having just a bunch of numbers written to the file I would like it to be understood by humans also. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean readable by humans?
For example: Do you want to that the parameters will have a different name? Other option is to use file append text method instead of only writing to it.

Comment: just concatenate the strings with paste or sprintf

Comment: I mean not just a bunch of numbers written without context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf`

```
templateText <- 
"####### Iteration number %i #############
Mean = %1.2f
median = %1.2f
std = %1.2f"

out <- sprintf(templateText, i, mean(x), median(x), sd(x))
cat(out)
```

Comment: Two thumbs up! This works perfectly! Note: i is the iteration index and x the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/):

```
results <- list()
results[["Iteration number 1"]] <- list(Mean=3, median=6, std=5)
results[["Iteration number 2"]] <- list(Mean=4, median=7, std=6.5)

library(yaml)
writeLines(as.yaml(results), con="results.yaml")
```

You data can be read back in:

```
results2 <- yaml.load_file("results.yaml")
```

And the file is quite readable:

```
Iteration number 1:
  Mean: 3.0
  median: 6.0
  std: 5.0
Iteration number 2:
  Mean: 4.0
  median: 7.0
  std: 6.5
```

Comment: I never knew about `yaml`.  Very nice!

Comment: Thx u too, will check ur method later, kinda of busy now.